How to merge multiple images into one in Java?
I have multiple images (.jpg/.jpeg/.png) in form of Spring's MultiPartFile. I need to transform them into a single MultiPartFile with images places vertically - preferably PDF, but other image formats are also fine.
I have tried using iText and GroupDocs solutions, but they require paid licence for commercial use. Is there any free-to-use solution?

You could create one huge jpeg in an ImageBuffer. And converting a .jpg to .pdf can use an other library than the commercial iText,

If you want to merge images together, I would make sure you convert all of the incoming images to an array of BufferedImage and stitch them together like so. This class utilizes Java's AWT library for reading and drawing images to a Graphics2D context.
I made the options highly configurable, so you can choose which direction they flow and even their alignment. It is an immutable record that comes with a builder and defaults.
The options (defaults in parens) allow you to control the:

outerPadding ~ padding around the resulting image (0)
inset ~ gap between images (0)
backgroundColor ~ background color (transparent)
flowDirection ~ direction of flow (vertical)
alignment ~ alignment of images (center)

You just need to pre-compute the dimensions and then draw each image onto the new image.
Implementation
In the example below, I saved three images to ~/Pictures and generate a resulting image in the same directory.
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class ImageCombiner {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path homePath = Path.of(System.getProperty("user.home"));

        BufferedImage[] imagesToCombine = {
                readImage(homePath.resolve("Pictures/a.png").toString()),
                readImage(homePath.resolve("Pictures/b.jpg").toString()),
                readImage(homePath.resolve("Pictures/c.bmp").toString()),
        };

        Options options = Options.builder()
                .outerPadding(10)
                .inset(10)
                .backgroundColor(Color.GRAY)
                .build();

        BufferedImage result = combineImages(imagesToCombine, options);

        writeImage(result, homePath.resolve("Pictures/result.png").toString());
    }

    public static BufferedImage combineImages(BufferedImage[] images) {
        return combineImages(images, DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
    }

    public static BufferedImage combineImages(BufferedImage[] images, Options options) {
        if (images == null || images.length == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Image array cannot be null or empty");
        }

        for (BufferedImage image : images) {
            if (image == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Images cannot contain null elements");
            }
        }

        Dimension imageDimensions = calculateDimensions(images, options);

        BufferedImage combinedImage = new BufferedImage(imageDimensions.width, imageDimensions.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = combinedImage.createGraphics();

        g2d.setColor(options.backgroundColor);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, combinedImage.getWidth(), combinedImage.getHeight());

        renderImages(images, options, g2d, combinedImage.getWidth(), combinedImage.getHeight());

        g2d.dispose();

        return combinedImage;
    }

    private static Dimension calculateDimensions(BufferedImage[] images, Options options) {
        int totalWidth = options.outerPadding, totalHeight = options.outerPadding;

        switch (options.flowDirection) {
            case HORIZONTAL -> {
                for (BufferedImage image : images) {
                    totalWidth += image.getWidth() + options.inset;
                    totalHeight = Math.max(totalHeight, image.getHeight() + 2 * options.inset);
                }
            }
            case VERTICAL -> {
                for (BufferedImage image : images) {
                    totalWidth = Math.max(totalWidth, image.getWidth() + 2 * options.inset);
                    totalHeight += image.getHeight() + options.inset;
                }
            }
        }

        totalWidth += options.outerPadding;
        totalHeight += options.outerPadding;

        return new Dimension(totalWidth, totalHeight);
    }

    private static void renderImages(BufferedImage[] images, Options options, Graphics2D g2d, int containerWidth, int containerHeight) {
        int offsetX = options.outerPadding, offsetY = options.outerPadding;

        for (BufferedImage image : images) {
            int x = offsetX, y = offsetY;

            switch (options.flowDirection) {
                case HORIZONTAL -> {
                    y = calculateAlignedOffset(image.getHeight(), options.alignment, containerHeight);
                    g2d.drawImage(image, x, y, null);
                    offsetX += image.getWidth() + options.inset;
                }
                case VERTICAL -> {
                    x = calculateAlignedOffset(image.getWidth(), options.alignment, containerWidth);
                    g2d.drawImage(image, x, y, null);
                    offsetY += image.getHeight() + options.inset;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static int calculateAlignedOffset(int imageSize, Alignment alignment, int containerSize) {
        return switch (alignment) {
            case START -> 0;
            case CENTER -> (containerSize - imageSize) / 2;
            case END -> containerSize - imageSize;
        };
    }

    private static BufferedImage readImage(String path) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(Path.of(path).toFile());
        if (image == null) {
            throw new IOException("Failed to read image from path: " + path);
        }
        return image;
    }

    private static void writeImage(BufferedImage image, String path) throws IOException {
        if (!ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(path))) {
            throw new IOException("Failed to write image to path: " + path);
        }
    }

    private static final Options DEFAULT_OPTIONS = Options.builder().build();

    public enum FlowDirection { HORIZONTAL, VERTICAL }
    public enum Alignment { START, CENTER, END }

    public record Options(int outerPadding, int inset, Color backgroundColor, FlowDirection flowDirection, Alignment alignment) {
        private static final Color DEFAULT_BACKGROUND_COLOR = new Color(0, true);

        public Options {
            if (outerPadding < 0 || inset < 0) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Padding and inset must be non-negative");
            }
        }

        public static Builder builder() {
            return new Builder();
        }

        public static class Builder {
            private int outerPadding;
            private int inset;
            private Color backgroundColor = DEFAULT_BACKGROUND_COLOR;
            private FlowDirection flowDirection = FlowDirection.VERTICAL;
            private Alignment alignment = Alignment.CENTER;

            public Builder outerPadding(int outerPadding) {
                this.outerPadding = outerPadding;
                return this;
            }

            public Builder inset(int inset) {
                this.inset = inset;
                return this;
            }

            public Builder backgroundColor(Color backgroundColor) {
                this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
                return this;
            }

            public Builder flowDirection(FlowDirection flowDirection) {
                this.flowDirection = flowDirection;
                return this;
            }

            public Builder alignment(Alignment alignment) {
                this.alignment = alignment;
                return this;
            }

            public Options build() {
                return new Options(outerPadding, inset, backgroundColor, flowDirection, alignment);
            }
        }
    }
}

Caveats
Note: Keep in mind that I utilized records and the enhanced switch which may not be available in older versions of Java. If your version does not support records, you could use Lombok instead.
Although Lombok removes a lot of boilerplate, it is still more cumbersome that using a record.
@Getter
@ToString
@Builder
public static class Options {
    private static final Color DEFAULT_BACKGROUND_COLOR = new Color(0, true);
    private static final FlowDirection DEFAULT_FLOW_DIRECTION = FlowDirection.VERTICAL;
    private static final Alignment DEFAULT_ALIGNMENT = Alignment.CENTER;

    private final int outerPadding;
    private final int inset;

    @Builder.Default
    private Color backgroundColor = DEFAULT_BACKGROUND_COLOR;

    @Builder.Default
    private FlowDirection flowDirection = DEFAULT_FLOW_DIRECTION;

    @Builder.Default
    private Alignment alignment = DEFAULT_ALIGNMENT;

    // Optional: Validation in the constructor
    public Options(int outerPadding, int inset, Color backgroundColor, FlowDirection flowDirection, Alignment alignment) {
        if (outerPadding < 0 || inset < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Padding and inset must be non-negative");
        }
        this.outerPadding = outerPadding;
        this.inset = inset;
        this.backgroundColor = Objects.requireNonNullElse(backgroundColor, DEFAULT_BACKGROUND_COLOR);
        this.flowDirection = Objects.requireNonNullElse(flowDirection, DEFAULT_FLOW_DIRECTION);
        this.alignment = Objects.requireNonNullElse(alignment, DEFAULT_ALIGNMENT);
    }
}

If you do use Lombok, you can combine the @Builder annotation with your Options record:
@Builder
public record Options(int outerPadding, int inset, Color backgroundColor, FlowDirection flowDirection, Alignment alignment) {
    private static final Color DEFAULT_BACKGROUND_COLOR = new Color(0, true);

    public Options {
        if (outerPadding < 0 || inset < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Padding and inset must be non-negative");
        }
        backgroundColor = Objects.requireNonNullElse(backgroundColor, DEFAULT_BACKGROUND_COLOR);
        alignment = Objects.requireNonNullElse(alignment, Alignment.CENTER);
        flowDirection = Objects.requireNonNullElse(flowDirection, FlowDirection.VERTICAL);
    }
}


For similar usecases, I have used two solutions in the past.

Use Apache PDF Box: (https://pdfbox.apache.org/)

Apache PDF Box is fully Apache licensed and so can be used without any cost. Creating and manipulating images in PDFBox can be a little time consuming for first timers. There is a learning curve associated with it. It is quite powerful, and you can do almost everything that you can do with iText.

Apache FoP: (https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/)

Apache FOP (XSL:FO) internally uses PDF Box. You can create the layout of the PDF using XSL:FO (XML Stylesheets - Formatting Objects). You can create an XML or a Java Bean that implements a SAX Parser and pass it on to FO. It is comparatively easier than doing it directly on PDF Box.

Apache PDFBox can be used directly which is open source.
Or else, create a html with those pictures and then convert that html to pdf using openHtmlToPdf.
PDFBox sample (skip the scaling part if you do not need it):
 @PostMapping("/imagesToPdf")
public void uploadMultipleFiles(@RequestParam("files") List<MultipartFile> files) throws IOException{
    imagesToPDF("F:\\testsample.pdf", files);
}

private static void imagesToPDF(String pdfPath, List<MultipartFile> inputDirsAndFiles) throws IOException {
    try (PDDocument doc = new PDDocument()) {
        for (MultipartFile input : inputDirsAndFiles) {
            addImageToPDF(doc, input);
        }
        doc.save(pdfPath);
    }
}


private static void addImageToPDF(PDDocument doc, MultipartFile multipartFile) {
    try {
        PDImageXObject image  = LosslessFactory.createFromImage(doc,ImageIO.read(multipartFile.getInputStream())); 
        PDRectangle pageSize = PDRectangle.A4;

        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();
        float pageWidth = pageSize.getWidth();
        float pageHeight = pageSize.getHeight();
        float ratio = Math.min(pageWidth/width, pageHeight/height);
        float scaledW = width*ratio;
        float scaledH = height*ratio;
        float x = (pageWidth-scaledW)/2;
        float y = (pageHeight-scaledH)/2;

        PDPage page = new PDPage(pageSize);
        doc.addPage(page);
        try (PDPageContentStream contents = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page)) {
            contents.drawImage(image, x, y, scaledW, scaledH);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
}

In case you don't want to save it, instead of PDF path, use a ByteArrayOutputStream, e.g.
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream= new ByteArrayOutputStream();
doc.save(byteArrayOutputStream);
return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

Then either use the PDF file in byte[] format or convert to MultipartFile taking help from here:
https://www.baeldung.com/java-convert-byte-array-to-multipartfile

I would appreciate a code snippet, as I can't really make it work. I also don't want to save the file to disc, just cast it to MultiPartFile and pass it further.

I've added PDFbox sample code, hope it helps.
